# Recurrence Relation with n Poker Chips

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find a recurrence relation for number of ways to stack n poker chips if each poker chip is white, red, or blue and  a) Find the recurrence with no adjacent chips have the same color.  b) Find the recurrence of blue chips that may be adjacent but no chips that are red or white  can be adjacent to another chip that is red or white.

This problem refers to the recurrence relation but i'm very confused of how to simplify this problem in order to solve the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there are $F(n)$ ways to stack $n$ poker chips. How many ways are there, then, to stack $n+1$ poker chips assuming you know $F(n)$.

The first two cases (number of ways with no conditions, and then number of ways without two same-color adjacent chips) are similar.

The last case requires more than one term in the recurrence, since you need to consider the cases where a blue chip is last versus a red/white chip last separately.

Comment: for part a) I have something like a_n = 2a(n-1) + a(n-2) but i'm sure how to approach part b) at all

Comment: I think part a) is also wrong

Comment: For Part A) you don't need to go back two steps, just one. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For such problems it is useful to set up several linked recurrences, i.e., one variable for stacks ending in each color, and see how they relate. In your case, you can make one ending in blue by adding a blue chip to a stack ending in any color, you can create one ending in white by adding a white chip to stacks ending in blue or red, and so on. Once you have the system of recurrences you can try to reduce it.